# Centered number of votes looks out of place

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looks like the number of votes and the number of tags got moved to the center of the page instead of the left side. It's a bit confusing and for a few minutes I thought the whole page was bugged until I realize that is what happened:

[image: Screenshot with hand-drawn red circles. Upvote me!]

Especially for the votes this is very unclear. Is this intentional?

Comment: If you scroll down further, the Badges header is also out of place.

Comment: I think it's related to the fix for this - http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/horizontal-scrollbar-has-appeared-on-my-activity-tab

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fix should be in the next build. @ChrisF was correct on the source of this bug...